# Concerning a result of Formanek about $k[F_1,\ldots,F_n][F_{n+1}]=k[x_1,\ldots,x_n]$

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra, jacobian

A result of [E. Formanek](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/227101632_Two_notes_on_the_Jacobian_Conjecture) says:
Let $k$ be a field of characteristic zero and let $R=k[x_1,\ldots,x_n]$ be the polynomial ring in $n$ variables.
Let $F_1,\ldots,F_n \in R$ have invertible Jacobian in $R$ (namely, the Jacobian is a non-zero scalar).
If there exists $F_{n+1} \in R$ such that
$k[F_1,\ldots,F_n][F_{n+1}]=R$,
then $k[F_1,\ldots,F_n]=R$.

Now let $I$ be the ideal of $R$ generated by $F_1,\ldots,F_n$:
$I=\langle F_1\ldots,F_n \rangle= RF_1+\cdots+RF_n$.

Is it possible to prove the following claim by adjusting Formanek's proof:

> If there exists $F_{n+1} \in R$ such that
> $k[F_1,\ldots,F_n][F_{n+1}]+I=R$,
> then $k[F_1,\ldots,F_n]=R$.

Of course, if $I \subseteq k[F_1,\ldots,F_n][F_{n+1}]$, then this is just Formanek's result.

Now also asked in [MO](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/386410/concernig-a-result-of-e-formanek).
[This](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/366216/question-about-jacobian-subalgebra) is a relevant question.

Thank you very much!

Comment: Your condition is always satisfied . So, if what you ask is true , Jacobian conjecture will be true .

Comment: For which $F_{n+1}$? I was thinking about $F_{n+1}=x$ or $F_{n+1}=y$. But why if we take $F_{n+1}=F_1$ we get $k[F_1,\ldots.F_n] + \langle F_1,\ldots,F_n \rangle=R$?

Comment: Do you know how to prove $k[F_1,\ldots.F_n] + \langle F_1,\ldots,F_n \rangle=R$? I do not know how to prove this. But if this is true, then the two-dimensional JC is true, if I am not wrong.

Comment: If I am not wrong, it can be shown that for $F_{n+1}=x$ or $F_{n+1}=y$, my condition $k[F_1,\ldots,F_n,x]+I=R$ is satisfied. Did you mean that $k[F_1,\ldots,F_n]+I=R$ is satisfied (namely, for $F_{n+1} \in \{F_1,\ldots,F_n\}$)?

Comment: Please, could you explain "Your condition is always satisfied", namely, did you have a specific $F_{n+1}$ in mind? As I have commented above, but now with some more details, for the two-dimensional case $k[x,y]$: I think that it is possible to obtain (under change of variables) that $I=\langle F_1,F_2 \rangle= \langle h,y \rangle$, for some $h \in k[x]$. Then, if we choose $F_3=x$, we get $k[F_1,F_2][F_3]+I=k[F_1,F_2][x]+\langle h,y \rangle= k[x,y]$, so indeed in that case my condition is satisfied. So I guess you also had $F_3 \in \{x,y \}$ in mind.

Comment: Or you can prove that $k[F_1,F_2]+\langle F_1,F_2 \rangle = k[x,y]$, without any $F_3$? This would be interesting, since it would prove the two-dimensional JC...if I am not wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your condition $k[F_1,\ldots,F_n][F_{n+1}]+I=R$ is equivalent to $k[F_{n+1}]\to R/I$ is onto for a suitable $F_{n+1}\in R$. If $I=R$, there is nothing to prove (and Jacobian conjecture says this can not happen) and if not, the Jacobian condition says $R/I$ is a finite product of fields $L_1\times\cdots\times L_r$, where each $L_i$ is a finite extension of $k$. In characteristic zero, these are all simple extensions and then I will leave you to check that such an $F_{n+1}$ can be found.

Comment: Thank you very much!